# How to update two tables at the same time in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, How can I update the table2 based on the result of update in table1 at the same time if I updated the table1 to 1234 for example:

```
table1
SalesNo: 123


table2
SalesNo: 123
```

Then I updated the table1 from 123 to 1234, I want the result as this:

```
table1
SalesNo: 1234

table2
SalesNo: 1234
```

Comment: Just use 2 update statements, 1 for each table?

Comment: `UDPATE` in SQL always only updates a single table - if you need to update two tables, you need **two** `UPDATE` statements - no way around that.

Comment: Why do you want the same update twice, just for different tables?

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write two different `update` statements

```
update table1
set SalesNo = 1234
where SalesNo = 123 

update table2
set SalesNo = 1234
where SalesNo = 123
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy updates in one table to another table, you can create a trigger for update of the first table and put the update of the second table there.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @AlexanderRodriguez first your clarify exactly what you want in your question... then if a trigger is the answer you google a tutorial on how to build a trigger.